# Using a type as an indexer

Tags: c++, templates, syntactic-sugar, indexer

Consider a class containing a map of components, where each one is identified by its type, meaning each `Component` is unique by its type.

```
std::map<std::type_index, Component*>
```

With the use of templates and `typeof`, I created a getter for these components:

```
Physics *p = object.get<Physics>();
```

I am already very happy with it, but is there a way to use this template type as an indexer? Something like this:

```
Physics *p = object[Physics];
```

Comment: not sure, but you can overload `operator[]` but it needs to take a value as parameter, if it would be ok to call it as `objects[Physics()]` it is doable with the overhead of creating a temporary of the corresponding type. Otherwise you may need some macro magic

Comment: Side note: If you are already using templates, it is "nicer" if you specialize them for certain types, instead of a if-chain to compare the types.

Comment: What type do you want this to be `object.get[rand()%2?Physics:Biology]` ?

Comment: what about using typeid and it's hash value?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the best you can achieve **without resorting to macros** or creating unnecessary instances:

```
int main()
{
    map m;
    m[type_w<int>] = /* ... */;
}
```

Implementation:

```
template <typename T>
struct type_wrapper { using type = T; };

template <typename T>
inline constexpr type_wrapper<T> type_w{};

struct map
{
    template <typename T>
    void operator[](type_wrapper<T>) { }
};
```

[**live wandbox example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7wbRQK8r4ybjfZ9H)

Answer (score 0):

`Physics` is a type, and so you can't pass it to a function (an operator is just syntactic sugar for a function). What you can do is pass an instance:

```
Physics *p = object[Physics{}]; // assuming Physics is default-constructible
```

But if you can't create a `Physics` instance whenever, that solution won't work. Another solution is to create an `enum`, and pass that to the operator:

```
enum class types {
    Physics, SomethingElse
};

Physics *p = object[types::Physics];
```

Instead of using `typeof`, you have to compare the value of `types` passed to the function.